# Construct a new tensor from two existing ones in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to construct a new tensor `y` with shape `(b,n,c)` from an existing tensor `x` with shape `(b,m,c)` with `m<n` and an index tensor `idx` with shape `(b,m)` which tells me for each row in `x` (length `c`) where to put it in `y`.

Example with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
b=2
n=100
m=4
c=3
idx=np.array([[0,31,5,66],[1,73,34,80]]) # shape b x m
x=np.random.random((b,m,c))
y=np.zeros((b,n,c))
for i,cur_idx in enumerate(idx):
    y[i,cur_idx]=x[i]
```

This results in an array `y` which has zeros everywhere except at the positions given by `idx` where the value from `x` are inserted.

I need help to "translate" this code fragment into tensorflow.

Edit:
I do not want to create a variable but rather a constant tensor so tf.scatter_update cannot be used.

Comment: `tf.scatter` might help.

Comment: I would rather not want to create a variable but a constant tensor. I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

b = 2
n = 100
m = 4
c = 3

# Synthetic data
x = tf.reshape(tf.range(b * m * c), (b, m, c))
# Arbitrary indices: [0, 25, 50, 75], [1, 26, 51, 76]
idx = tf.convert_to_tensor(
    np.stack([np.arange(0, n, n // m) + i for i in range(b)], axis=0))

# Add index for the first dimension
idx = tf.concat([
    tf.tile(tf.range(b, dtype=idx.dtype)[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis], (1, m, 1)),
    idx[:, :, tf.newaxis]], axis=2)

# Scatter operation
y = tf.scatter_nd(idx, x, (b, n, c))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    y_val = sess.run(y)
    print(y_val[:, 20:30, :])
```

Output:

```
[[[ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [15 16 17]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]]]
```